# In general, can you use 32-bit drivers on a 64-bit OS?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, dell-studio

I currently have a 32-bit Windows 7 installation, and want to do a clean reinstall to 64-bit Windows 7.

If I back up my 32-bit drivers/download the original OEM 32-bit drivers for my new 64-bit installation, *will they work*?  Some? Hit or miss?

Windows 7, Dell Studio 1735 - 64-bit capable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 is pretty good when it comes to picking up new drivers. It would probably work, but I would suggest not to bother with backing them up. Windows picks most of them up upon boot and via Windows update, and you don't want to be stuck with 32-bit drivers on a 64-bit OS which could be hindering your performance. Certain ones (i.e. video card) I would recommend grabbing the latest manually, as the Windows update website doesn't seem to contain the latest revisions all the time.

Comment: would the internet drivers work, or how would I get the drivers to work for that w/o backup?

Comment: Windows 7 picks up most new hardware on boot. This is what I've experienced at least. At work I have made a generic Windows 7 ghost image on a desktop and applied it to a bunch of laptops and workstations without issues.

Comment: 32-bit drivers will flatly not work on a 64-bit Windows install.

Answer (score 3):

*Before* you do the clean install, go to Dell website and download drivers for 64bit and save them on a different partition or USB drive.   In particular, pickup the `chipset` and `ethernet` drivers.

Those backup drivers program never seems to save all the misc application that goes along with the driver.  You can still use it, but I won't solely depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like no one ever said this, so I thought I would:

### *No*, 32-bit drivers do not work on 64-bit Windows.

WOW64 is only for applications. Drivers must be compiled for the system on which they will be run.